# How do I start Tomcat on boot without having to provide a root password?

Tags: startup, password, root

I have Tomcat set up to launch at start up on my Ubuntu box.  Trouble is, I have to manually supply a root password on each boot.  Is it possible for this to be automated?  Do I just supply an command parm?  If so, what is the syntax?  Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm unsure about how you have pulled this off, but it does sound like you have tomcat start up when you log in rather than when the machine boots. Am I right?

Anyway, you should have it start when it boots. The following procedures should be done as root. When in use, init will do them as root.

#### The quick and dirty way:

Given that your start script is `/usr/local/tomcat/bin/startup.sh` the just add that line to the file `/etc/rc.local` and reboot.

#### The right way:

Make an upstart script. I haven't really done that before, but I saw this: https://gist.github.com/2924017 which might work.
Put the file (`tomcat.conf`) in `/etc/init/` and reboot.

As a service, you can start, stop, restart and get status on services by doing:

```
start tomcat
stop tomcat
restart tomcat
status tomcat
```

This is of course how all services in Ubuntu behave. (gdm, apache, ssh, etc..)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Yes.  I simply put it (command line statement) in the Startup Applications list.  It launches Tomcat provided I type in the root password quickly.  Many times, I don't type it fast enough and have to launch it from the terminal.

Comment: Remove it from startup applications and follow either of the two solutions. The most stable will be "The right way" while the fastest is probably adding a line to /etc/rc.local.

Comment: Thank you!!!  I am by no measure a sys admin. I followed your advice and it works great - again thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

One way to start the tomcat on the startup is to run it using cron using the @reboot attribute:

open up a terminal and type :

```
sudo crontab -e
```

at the end of the file enter the command:

```
@reboot /`PATH_TO_WHERE_TOMCAT_INSTALLED`/bin/startup.sh
```

save the file and exit.

The above command will run the command once everytime computer boots up.